# Sequelize — use UNIX timestamp for DATE fields

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a way to force Sequelize use UNIX Timestamp as default time format **both** for createdAt/updatedAt timestamps **and** for custom-defined Sequelize.DATE field types?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At any given moment in time, there are two possible dates (depending on one's position relative to the international date line): that is, converting from a UNIX timestamp to a date requires one to consider the timezone.

For example, the UNIX timestamp `946684800` is `2000-01-01 00:00:00Z`.  Whilst this represents the first day of the new millenium pretty much everywhere east of the Atlantic, it's still millenium eve everywhere to the west of that ocean.  So which date does it represent?

Whilst it's *possible* to convert from a date to a timestamp, one must define one's own convention for so doing (e.g. represent a given date as midnight in UTC) or else the same date may be represented differently upon each encoding.  Generally speaking, this is a bad idea which may have all sorts of unintended consequences.

There is a reason that the `DATE` data type exists: it is *the* correct way to store a date.  Use it.

Comment: Storing unix time is a valid way to store time (generally speaking) - interpreting the local Date/Time from it is just a matter of calculating the local/seasonal offset from the UTC time.

Comment: @rjarmstrong: Isn't that exactly what my answer says?  My point was that the OP was asking how to store a date (and a date alone) using a timestamp.

Comment: The problem is you said that the DATE data type is the correct way to store a date - which is misleading. I'm happy to remove down vote if you qualify this statement with something like 'in Sequelize the recommended way is to use the DATE type'. 

Unfortunately the Sequelize DATE type also has a limitation in that it does not store milliseconds from what I can tell which may indicate why the timestamp was of interest.

Comment: @rjarmstrong, I wouldn't agree even with 'in Sequelize the recommended way is to use the DATE type'. It really depends on what exactly you want to store. When you say you want to store "date", you must understand whether you want to store the date as the client perceives it (a local time, a time selected in a calendar), or you want to record an unambiguous point in time (regardless of its client-side representation). By Unix timestamp you can determine the exact point in time. By date you can determine the client-side representation. To get both you need some extra info in both cases.

Comment: 99% of the time the correct way to store a date is as an duration from the epoch e.g. UNIX timestamps. Then when you present it to the user, you ask the OS/browser to do so according to the user's system settings. People obsess about timezones but some users are not even using a Gregorian calendar (!!!).

Answer (score 7):

While `eggyal`'s answer is the proper way to do things in MySQL, some of us might be working in an environment or team that requires us to use a unix timestamp instead of a datetime / timestamp.

I found that a great way to accomplish this is to use hooks inside of sequelize. At the bottom of each of your models, you can add this code:

```
{
        tableName: 'Addresses',
        hooks : {
            beforeCreate : (record, options) => {
                record.dataValues.createdAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                record.dataValues.updatedAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
            },
            beforeUpdate : (record, options) => {
                record.dataValues.updatedAt = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

This will insert the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields as unix timestamps.

Comment: The fields `tableName` and `hooks` are part of the options object of a model. It's the argument after the attributes object when using .define()

Answer (score 1):

No or at least not yet.
CreatedAt is set using the utils.now function in sequelize.  That function uses the javascript Date function with no additional arguments.  Squelize could be modified to change the way it calls Date but there is no code to do that in the current version.
see [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/utils.js)

You could however disable the createdAt and other timestamps and use raw queries to set your own.  However then you're sacrificing the functionality of sequelize.
Best solution is probably to convert those fields to unix time in your business logic before using them.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about such solition. But what about «However then you're sacrificing the functionality of sequelize.»? You mean I wont be able to perform some date-specified queries?

Comment: sequelize maps objects to tables.  That mapping provides a object oriented interface to the database.  Without those values being set, sequelize won't be able to check if the object has been updated.  You will have have to rewrite that logic.